# Como puedo obtener un arreglo desde LS y añadir un objeto a el?

Tags: javascript, array, objeto, local-storage

Tengo un problema cuando intento crear y guardar objetos dentro de un arreglo y guardarlo en local storage. Me resulta, pero cada vez que añado uno nuevo se crea un arreglo dentro del arreglo anterior y no se como manejarlo. Les dejo el código y lo que sale por consola para que quede mas claro.

```
    const form = document.querySelector('form');
const enviarBtn = document.querySelector('#enviar');

enviarBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Evita que se envíe el formulario
  
  const datosVehiculo = {
    nombre: document.getElementById('nombre').value,
    rut: document.getElementById('rut').value,
    patente: document.getElementById('patente').value,
    marca: document.getElementById('marca').value,
    modelo: document.getElementById('modelo').value,
    color: document.getElementById('color').value
  };
  
  //Si hay datos 
  if (localStorage.getItem('datosVehiculo')) {

    const datosGuardados = localStorage.getItem("datosVehiculo");
    const datosVehiculoGuardados = JSON.parse(datosGuardados);

    const arrVehiculo =[datosVehiculoGuardados]

    console.log(datosVehiculoGuardados)

    const arrDatos = [...arrVehiculo, datosVehiculo];

    localStorage.setItem("datosVehiculo", JSON.stringify(arrDatos))


    console.log("Hay datos en LS");
  } else {
    // Si no hay datos
    localStorage.setItem("datosVehiculo", JSON.stringify(datosVehiculo))
  }
});
```

[image: Lo que muestra por consola, para que quede mas claro]

Answer (score 0):

Pude solucionarlo, mi error fue que no añadí el primer objeto dentro de un arreglo, entonces cuando lo obtenía para añadir uno nuevo, era un objeto y no me permitía ocupar spread operator para obtener la copia de ese arreglo y añadirle uno nuevo.

Adjunto mi solución por si alguien mas pasa por esto.

```
//Si hay datos 
  if (localStorage.getItem('datosVehiculo')) {

    const datosGuardados = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("datosVehiculo"));

    const arrVehiculo =[...datosGuardados, datosVehiculo]

    localStorage.setItem("datosVehiculo", JSON.stringify(arrVehiculo))
  } else {
    // Si no hay datos
    const nuevoArr = [datosVehiculo]
    
    localStorage.setItem("datosVehiculo", JSON.stringify(nuevoArr))
  }
```